# Can't duplicate apps from Apple (like Terminal.App) in macOS 13

Tags: macos, terminal, zsh, rosetta-2

I am using conda a lot and for some packages and environments I need x86_64 architecture. I did this by duplicating my Terminal.app and starting one duplicate with Rosetta (as described here: https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-install-miniconda-x86-64-apple-m1-side-by-side-on-mac-book-m1-a476936bfaf0). Unfortunately, I can't duplicate my Terminal.app anymore since macOS 13. Does anyone already have a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have the same problem with react-native, nor even with sudo can duplicate it, but you can use the `arch` command for that:

```sh
arch -arch_name binary args ...

# example with react-native: 
arch -x86_64 npx react-native run-ios --simulator "iPhone 14"
```

See `man arch` for more details

Comment: can I use this `arch` the restart the terminal with it like executing `arch -x86_64 source ~/.zshrc`?

Comment: `arch -x86_64 zsh` would set it. So if you exec just `arch` it give you the current architecture running so, before `arch -x86_64 zsh` would be **arm64** and after will be **i386**

Comment: Thanks, this really helps. Would be great, if there would be a solution to create a duplicate still. Or maybe a shortcut, that starts with Rosetta :).

Comment: I suspect that disabling SIP would allow you to duplicate it.  But I also suspect that Software Update will undo it.  I made improvements to my "Press and Hold" which were wiped out by the next Software Update.  But maybe with SIP disabled, you could make a copy in a location like ~/Desktop that would not be removed by Software Update.  I have a persistent copy of my PressAndHold changes but MacOS will only use the standard location.

Answer (score 6):

I found the answer on the [Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/718666):

```
% env /usr/bin/arch -arm64 /bin/zsh --login
% arch
arm64 


% env /usr/bin/arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh --login
% arch
x86_64
```

I tried this and it’s working as expected.

Comment: Why `--login` is needed here?